# Performing a Segue from a UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to create a custom UIView that will, when tapped, segue to a new view controller. I'd like to do this programmatically rather than in Interface Builder. How do I get a reference to the destination view controller when I'm doing this? I assume I don't just create one and set it as the next view or something, so where does the reference come from? Since when it's done in the storyboard you simply choose where you want the segue to have as the destination, it's not an issue there, however programmatically I don't understand where that reference comes from.

I'm doing this in Swift as well. I don't think that really makes a big difference, but it might change something.

I tried using a UIView with a tapGestureRecognizer added, which then performed the segue when tapped, however I was getting an unrecognized selector error.

Answer (score 1):

If you declared your UIViewController in storyboard you have to set its Storyboard Id, and then, instead of performing segue you can use something like this (didn't run it, but done exact the same thing in obj-c, so I think it will do well):

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil);
let vc : MyUIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myVCStoryboardID")     as MyUIViewController;
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil);
```