# Present another view controller scene created in main.storybord from a SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsnotificationcenter, skscene

I'm struggling trying to present a view controller called GameEndViewController, I have created in main.storyboard with som buttons and labels using auto layout from a SKScene called PlayGameScene. I don't know how to use NSNotificationCenter to make the GameViewController present the GameEndViewController.

Can anybody tell me how to use NSNotificationCenter to present the GameEndViewController from the PlayGameScene using swift, or link me to a site where I can learn it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too broad: there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use NSNotificationCenter to present new views. NSNotifications can be used for one part of your app to tell another part of your app that something asynchronous happened, but that does not sound like what you are asking for.

To present a new view controller when your game ends create a segue to it in storyboard and then trigger that segue programatically as described [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27224165/2466193).

However, as an alternative, consider remaining in the same view controller and instead presenting a 'game end' SKSCene in your SKView as that may give a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that i can use NSNotificationCenter to tell the view controller of the SKScene to change view by triggering a segue created in the storyboard.

I wrote the following code to the GameViewController:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showGameEndViewController", name: "showGameEndViewController", object: nil)
}
func showGameEndViewController() -> Void {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("gameOverSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Working as a receiver for the NSNotificationCenter message.

Next i added the sender code to the SKScene:

```
        self.view?.presentScene(nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showGameEndViewController", object: nil)
```

And finally i created the segue in the main.storyboard between the GameViewController and the GameEndViewController.